# unittest async mocks doesnt't work with pytest?

Tags: unit-testing, asynchronous, mocking, pytest, python-3.5

```
async def test_coro(id):
    print("pass")

async def test_coro2():
    print("pass")

async def mock_test_coro(id):
    print("pass")

async def mock_test_coro2():
    print("hj")

class Test(AioHTTPTestCase):
    async def get_application(self):
        app = web.Application(debug=True)
        return app

   @unittest_run_loop
   @patch(__name__ + '.test_coro', side_effect=(lambda id: mock_test_coro(id)))
   @patch(__name__ + '.test_coro2', side_effect=(lambda: mock_test_coro2()))
   async def test_1(self, test_coro, test_coro2):
       await test_coro2()
       await test_coro(0)
```

I have fail in this test because (no parameter)

```
> test_coro = <AsyncMock name='test_coro2' id='139942609979472'>
> test_coro2 = <AsyncMock name='test_coro' id='139942609417456'>
```

why it so? (if there are more than 2 mocks - it shuffles they in random order)

for sync functions it was working fine

Answer (score 1):

important is patch applying order,
last argument is patch on the top and first is patch at the bottomn

```
   @unittest_run_loop
   @patch(__name__ + '.test_coro2', side_effect=(lambda: mock_test_coro2()))
   @patch(__name__ + '.test_coro', side_effect=(lambda id: mock_test_coro(id)))
   async def test_1(self, test_coro, test_coro2):
       await test_coro2()
       await test_coro(0)
```